# Does every $G$-by-$C_2$ extension split?

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, group-extensions

Given a group $G$ and a short exact sequence

$$1 \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 1$$

does the extension always split? That is, is it always true that $E = G \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The only $K$s for which every $G$-by-$K$ extensions split are the free groups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is that easy to see?

Comment: @RyleeLyman This property is true for free groups because you can extend set-theoretic lifts of the generators to a homomorphism. Conversely, if a group is not free, take the exact sequence corresponding to a presentation of it (in particular, the group in the middle is free). This can't split because subgroups of free groups are free.

Comment: ahh, that is clear. thanks!

Comment: Or: The property that every extension of $G$-by-$P$ group splits is the definition of $P$ being projective. Projectives are co-factors of free objects. So that would mean that there exists a group $H$ with $P*H$ free; since subgroup of free is free (this is special for groups), then $P$ is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, e.g. $E$ could be $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: well that's a bummer. thanks!

Comment: Also, the doubling map $1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}  \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 1$ doesn't split.